# Is it possible to get a window from behind the taskbar without having activated windows?

Tags: windows, taskbar

I accidentally dragged a window beneath the task bar somehow and now closing and reopening that app continues to open the window in that position and it's stuck. The common solution to this problem is to autohide the taskbar and you can get to the window but I recently set up this PC and planned to use a gifted windows key for windows 7 which failed on Windows 10, I need to wait before I spend the money on a new key and I can't change settings to hide the taskbar without an activated copy.

Is there any solution except to go buy a windows key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the icon on the task bar, then press and hold the Windows key and press the <kbd>↑</kbd> key (up arrow).  This will send the window to the top of the screen.

You can also use the left and right arrows (<kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>) to make the window change its size/switch screens if you have multiple monitors.

Answer (score 0):

All mouse activities can always done with the keyboard, and some elementary ones are worth knowing.

You can try this on a visible window to see how it works.

1. When the window in question selected (it *is* after starting teh program, if you don't click anywhere), press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. The little menu on the top left will open.
2. Press <kbd>M</kbd> (for Move)
3. Press the <kbd>Cursor Up</kbd> key several times, until the window is visible.
4. Press <kbd>RET</kbd> to end the activity.