# How to restore invisible/offscreen windows (Windows 10/11)

Tags: windows

How do you find/focus/restore a window in Windows if it is

1. Not selectable on screen (Can have size zero, or can be behind the task bar)
2. Not represented in the taskbar or the Alt-Tab cycle.

If it can be selected/get keyboard focus, then it can be restored. A modal dialog can be restored by focusing the window that opened it, because that focuses the dialog. But if it's non modal and has no taskbar icon, then what?

Example: Open a non-modal dialog that is not represented on the taskbar (I tried Notepad++ settings dialog). Now drag the dialog under the taskbar. How can I get it back without having to un-pin the taskbar to see it?

This question is almost asked here, but not quite. All answers here apply only windows that can be focuses, e.g. have an icon on the task bar. In such situations selecting the window is easy via the task bar. From there on restoring it can be done with Win+ArrowKey for example.
[Is it possible to get a window from behind the taskbar without having activated windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1190607/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a dialog can only be moved if it has the focus.
With or without a title bar, the dialog will
obey the key combination of
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.
It can then be moved by the arrow-keys, and will also follow
the mouse (blindly).

Otherwise, it will require a AutoHotKey or PowerShell
script to cycle through all dialogs and move on-screen
the ones that are off.

Comment: So if we don't count scripting solutions as available to regular users, then there is no way? Was this always the case in windows? I think I recall it not being possible to drag windows below the taskbar.

The Alt+Spacebar+M requires focus and only applies to windows with a standard window menu, something that becoming rare these days. Unsure if there is a different way of enabling the move state which doesn't rely on choosing it from the window menu?

Comment: The Alt+Spacebar+M applies to notepad++ Settings - I checked. I don't know of another method.

Comment: Yup, it works on the n++ preferences, I chose it as an example of a non-modal dialog. They can be dragged behind the taskbar, but unlike a modal dialog they can't be focused again by focusing the parent form. So you can't send the alt+space shortcut to them!